# exception when converting to thumbnail in file upload

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, image-uploading

When I tried to upload a large size image(2.3MB), I got following exception. I use a thumbnail creation jar for thumbnail creation(thumbnailator-0.4.2-all.jar). The file is getting uploaded fine, but I am not able to create thumbnail from it and it shows the exception.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Java heap space
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:453)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
```

I use JSP, with apache tomcat 5.5, eclipse helios as my development tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message gives you a pretty good clue:

`Java heap space`

You've run out of heap memory.  To create a thumbnail your image is probably being decoded to a bitmapped format, which can require quite a bit of memory for a large/high-resolution image file.

You can allocate more memory to your server instance using the `-Xmx` argument.  [This thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/421341/Tomcat/change-JVM-setting-Xms-Xmx) may be helpful, if you're not sure where to set this option.

Answer (score 0):

i refered [this](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2011/12/increasing-heap-size-in-eclipse) tutorial and my problem is solved now. Thanks @aroth